# start end date & dropdown menu from mysql in one html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a html or php page (for some own learning process) which can input 3 selection and then display there results in next page.

1- input Start Date 
2- input End Date
3- Show Service Name in drop down menu via mysql query to get services names from the table

So far I have managed to get the start and end table and drop down menu which successfully query the services table and shows the name, but the problem is that when i click submit i can see the results of start and end date but i am unable to see how can i add services selection in the posting. 
This is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#start_datepicker").datepicker();
                $("#end_datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:62.5%;">
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="start_datepicker"> <br />
            End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker"><br />
            <select name="srvname">
            <?php
                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'SQLPASS', 'radius')
                or die ('Cannot connect to db');

                $result = $conn->query("select srvname name from rm_services");

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit:">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is test.php which will per form action shows the date

```
  <?php
$STARTDATE = $_POST['startdate'];
$ENDDATE = $_POST['enddate'];
$SRVNAME = $_POST['srvname']; //gets the value -> $row["id"]
echo "<h2>You have entered the following information:</h2>";
echo "<pre>$STARTDATE</pre> ";
echo "<pre>$ENDDATE</pre>";
echo "<pre>$SRVNAME</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: You have a few HTML errors. Look at the `<form>` and `<html>` elements and their closings. Also you are only selecting `srvname` not `id` or `name`.

Comment: thank you for your pointers, now i have managed to correct the code and now three Input boxes are showing with one submit button, but its submitting only start-end dates to test.php page, its not displaying or submitting the SERVICES names to test.php

Comment: Can you update to what you now have?

Comment: Ok I have updated the main post with updated code as reply box not allowing to post long texts.

Comment: You never set `$srvname`. Also you have multiple `html` elements still and `body` elements.

Comment: @chris85
Thank you for your followup and time.
Ok I have updated the code, can you please check now? still srvname not showing in test.php results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work, and for the future: if you post something on stackoverflow, please post formatted code, it's way easier to edit and especially to read it...

your index.php or whatever...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#start_datepicker").datepicker();
                $("#end_datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body style="font-size:62.5%;">
        <form action="test.php" method="post"> 
            Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="start_datepicker"> <br />
            End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker"><br />
            <select name="srvname">
            <?php
                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'SQLPASS', 'radius') 
                or die ('Cannot connect to db');

                $result = $conn->query("select id, name from rm_services");

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit:"> 
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

your test.php

```
<?php
$STARTDATE = $_POST['startdate'];
$ENDDATE = $_POST['enddate'];
$SRVNAME = $_POST['srvname']; //gets the value -> $row["id"]
echo "<h2>You have entered the following information:</h2>";
echo "<pre>$STARTDATE</pre> ";
echo "<pre>$ENDDATE</pre>";
echo "<pre>$SRVNAME</pre>";
?>
```

I didn't test it, but actually it should work...

Comment: markus
Still I can see the Start end date , but service name not showing in test.php results

Comment: http://www3.kloiberm.com/so/ --> this one works perfectly... with the written code above, the only thing i've changed was the database and of course the query....

Comment: well the services names are appearing, but when i submit the selections, then the next page responsible to show the the results i.e test.php page showing only dates , and no services are appearing in the result.

Comment: check via pressing Ctrl + U in the browser of the index.php if the <option value="VAALLUEE">Name</option> has a value...cause if value="" than nothing will appear on the test.php page...

Comment: OK finally Got it :) thank you all for your support and replies for such a dubm query :) thank you again